# Cygwin: Is it safe to pipe from /dev/clipboard to clip?

Tags: bash, cygwin, clipboard, pipe

I am using [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on windows.

Given a long list of strings in the clipboard:

```
mail
know
trial
posture
wind
census
shelf
concrete
moon
fee
```

If I want to "unwrap" them, is it safe to use such a command:

```
cat /dev/clipboard | tr -d "\n" | tr "\r" "," | clip
```

In my example, this produces the result `mail,know,trial,posture,wind,census,shelf,concrete,moon,fee` as intended, but is it safe? I have the fear that maybe if I am unlucky, the last element of the pipe (`clip`) can "spoil" the first one.